# Opening Material on event click with Angular Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar with an Angular project. I want to trigger the opening of a dropdown menu when the user selects an event on the calendar. I have only found JQuery solutions so far and nothing that my limited knowledge is able to translate into angular. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's doable with ViewChild.

Assuming you are using an Angular Select, set a template variable for the control in the template: mine is #openMe

```
<mat-select #openMe>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

In the component, add the view child:

```
@ViewChild("openMe") iCanBeOpened: any;
```

Now, all you need is the logic:

```
calendarSelect(event: SomeEvent){ 
   setTimeout(() => {
        this.iCanBeOpened.toggle(true);
   });
}
```

Comment: I'm using Material Menu - I can trigger the modal programmatically but struggling to open the modal over the calendar. Currently, It appears in the bottom of the page and not over the actual event on the calendar

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

There is a *this.myViewChildMenu.openMenu()* there documented. If that doesn't work, post some code. Otherwise it's guessing here